# Call a function in mainActivity from another class

Tags: android, dialog

Okay so i am displaying my privacy policy in a custom dialog box, now i want to call a method in the MainActivity (where this dialog box is called) whenever the user clicks the accept Button on the dialog box. How should i do it ?

My ViewDialog class :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewDialog {

    public void showDialog(final Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        WebView webView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.webViewPolicy);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Policy Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/policy.html");

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

My Call from MainActivity :

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
alert.showDialog(this, "Privacy Policy");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `interface` like so:

```
public class ViewDialog {

    public interface OnAction {
        void accepted();
        void declined();
    }

    private OnAction listener;

    public ViewDialog(Context context) {
        ...
        this.listener = (MyActivity)context;
        ...
    }

}
```

And use it in your `Activity` like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends ... implements ViewDialog.OnAction {
    ...    

    @Override 
    public void accepted() {
        // execute action when use accepts;
    }

    @Override 
    public void declined() {
        // execute action when use declines;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can use `OnAction` listener in your `ViewDialog` class like so:

```
this.listener.accepted();
```

This will call `accepted()` method in your `Activity` and execute code that you have written there.

**P.S.** do not forget to pass this as listener when initialising `ViewDialog` instance like so:

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog(this);
```

---

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) MainActivity.class:-------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
    // Rather than passing an activity as argument, pass a WeakReference referring to this activity.
    alert.showDialog(new WeakReference<MainActivity>(MainActivity.this), "Privacy Policy");

}

public void mainActivityMethodToCallWhenPolicyIsAccepted(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Policy Accepted Main Activity Method" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

2) ViewDialog.class:-------

```
public class ViewDialog {

public void showDialog(WeakReference<MainActivity> weakReference, String msg){
    if(weakReference != null) {
        final MainActivity activity = weakReference.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            //dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

            WebView webView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.webViewPolicy);

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
            text.setText(msg);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, "Policy Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    activity.mainActivityMethodToCallWhenPolicyIsAccepted();
                }
            });

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/policy.html");

            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
}
```